# how to do Multidimensional Arrays

Tags: php, arrays, multidimensional-array

i have problem with this code. i want make the output look like this.

```
array(‘keyword’=>array(
    0=>'url1',
    1=>'url2',
))
```

currently this is my code. it only show me one url but actually theres a lot more. can someone please help me.

```
   $data = array();

           foreach ($response->Items->Item as $row)

           {
           $data[$keyword] = $row->DetailPageURL;
           }

           return $data;
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try with -

```
$data[$keyword][] = $row->DetailPageURL;
```

Answer (score 0):

Replace with this code....

```
  $data = array();

           foreach ($response->Items->Item as $row)

           {
           $data[$keyword][] = $row->DetailPageURL;
           }

           return $data;
```